# Count days from start_date to end_date or end of month

Tags: sql, mariadb

With datediff() I can count the days between two dates, but how can I count the days between the later date or the end of the month and the start date?

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (id int, start_date datetime, end_date datetime, jan int);

INSERT INTO table1 (id, start_date, end_date) VALUES 
(1, '2016-12-12', '2017-01-17'), 
(2, '2017-01-10', '2017-01-10'), 
(3, '2017-01-10', '2017-02-10'), 
(4, '2017-01-03', '2017-02-03'),
(5, '2016-12-03', '2017-02-03');
```

If I run:

```
select id, month(start_date) as month, datediff(end_date, start_date) as diff
from table1;
```

it returns

```
id  month   diff
1   12      36
2   1       0
3   1       31
4   1       31
5   12      62
```

but I would like it to return:

```
id  month   diff
1   12      19
5   12      28
1   1       17
2   1       0
3   1       21
4   1       28
5   1       31
3   2       10
4   2       3
5   2       3
```

I'm trying to get the amount of days in a month a event occurs by month.

I've created a separated query to update a new column with the values, but ideally it shouldn't have a new column, since I would need several new columns for each year-month combination and one for each year-month combination:

```
update table1 set jan= case 
when start_date >= "2017-01-01" and end_date <= last_day("2017-01-01") then datediff(end_date, start_date)+1
when start_date >= "2017-01-01" and start_date <= last_day("2017-01-01") and end_date > last_day("2017-01-01") then datediff(last_day("2017-01-01"), start_date)+1
when start_date < "2017-01-01" and end_date between "2017-01-01" and last_day("2017-01-01") then datediff(end_date, "2017-01-01")+1
when start_date < "2017-01-01" and end_date > last_day("2017-01-01") then day(last_day("2017-01-01"))
else null
end;
```

Comment: An update won't work, you need more rows.  There are 5 source rows and 10 output rows and 5 is mentioned 3 times. Ie the number or rows per input is variable

Comment: @RickJames of course. I used that in the DDL example. See id 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is going to be getting multiple rows... so let's take a different tack.

This ends up being trivial if you have a calendar table: a table with a row-per-date (and a bunch of individual columns and indices):

```
SELECT Table1.id, Calendar.calendar_month, COUNT(*)
FROM Table1
JOIN Calendar
  ON Calendar.calendar_date >= start_date
     AND Calendar.calendar_date < end_date
GROUP BY Table1.id, Calendar.calendar_month
ORDER BY Table1.id, MIN(Calendar.calendar_date)
```

<kbd>[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/187d1/4/0)</kbd>

Comment: MariaDB's "Sequence tables" can create such a Calendar on the fly.

Comment: For onsie twosie queries, sure.  But a permanent calendar table is a beautiful thing, especially since it can hold stuff not easy to generate from a strict sequence; holidays, fiscal year and period (especially when using a 52/53 week calendar, like in retail).  And especially if the resultant sequence would be large, where indices would help.  Without looking at the feature I don't know if the feature would work here, or would generate a table per grouping, or what.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for.

```
select  month(start_date) as month, 
    datediff(LAST_DAY(start_date), start_date) as diff
from table1

UNION ALL

select  month(end_date) as month,
    IF(end_date < LAST_DAY(start_date), datediff(start_date, end_date), 
datediff(end_date, LAST_DAY(start_date)))
from table1;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e5767/40)

Comment: Near, but in case the first event was 2 months before? Like id 5 http://sqlfiddle.com/?_escaped_fragment_=9/4e5767/40#!9/42fe04/3

Comment: 2017-12-03 and 2017-02-03 are not 2 months apart. You meant 2016-12-03 and 2017-02-03?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I wanted to take into account where the event occurs in month 12 and ends next year at month 02 or 03.

Comment: Check the latest query to know exactly what I'm looking for, *sans* new column. Probably my issue would need a subquery.

Comment: Suggest this answer be deleted since it does not handle >2 months.